# Excessive heat with Corsair H80i

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, water-cooling

I've recently purchased a Corsair H80i (liquid cooling), but the CPU temperatures are actually higher than with stock fan cooler.

My build: CoolerMaster GX550W, AMD FX 6300, ECS GTX 560, Kingston 8GB 1300MHz, Generic HDD, all on top of a ASUS M5A97 R2.0.

When I bought the FX6300, I used to get about 50°C maximum temperature at peak times (playing games) with the stock fan. Now that I've installed the H80i that number goes up to 65°C. Normal operation temperature is around 30°C, which, I think, sounds relatively reasonable. But I'm really worried about the CPU temp at high usage, which is indeed much higher than what a normal fan reaches.

At normal usage, the radiator fans stay on a steady 2.2k RPM, roughly half their capacity, going all the way to the maximum speed when gaming. This is also uncomfortable because the stock H80i fans are very noisy.

I've installed the H80i using the pre-applied thermal paste, if that's of any use.

Comment: Your PSU is good for about 1.5 of your systems. No need to worry about that.

Comment: Reapply the paste making sure to remove any dry one first.

Comment: The fans on this cooler generate less noise then the stock fan.  The only thing that could cause this behavior is a bad thermal paste application.